# PHP+MySQL, output results by category

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, iterator, wordpress

I'm trying to hack the WP plugin 'Contact Form 7' (with the DB extension) to output the results to my liking after the user has submitted the form.  I understand why the plugin has to arrange the DB the way it does, but I'm having trouble separating the entries.  Usually I would have an index to work with but here I do not.

Here is what my table looks like.

```
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
|   submit_time   | form_name |   field_name    |     field_value     | field_order | file |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | text-796        | Mindi               |           0 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | text-664        | Smith               |           1 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | text-635        | New York            |           2 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | menu-359        | A friend of Sarah's |           3 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | textarea-518    |                     |           4 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | file-29         |                     |           5 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | textarea-652    |                     |           6 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | Submitted Login | admin               |        9999 | NULL |
| 1360190186.3500 | RSVP 2    | Submitted From  | ::1                 |       10000 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | text-796        | Joe                 |           0 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | text-664        | Blow                |           1 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | text-635        | Somewhere           |           2 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | menu-359        | A friend of Bob's   |           3 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | textarea-518    |                     |           4 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | file-29         |                     |           5 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | textarea-652    |                     |           6 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | Submitted Login | admin               |        9999 | NULL |
| 1360191326.9700 | RSVP 2    | Submitted From  | ::1                 |       10000 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | text-796        | Once                |           0 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | text-664        | Again               |           1 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | text-635        | Somewhere           |           2 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | menu-359        | A friend of Bob's   |           3 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | textarea-518    |                     |           4 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | file-29         |                     |           5 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | textarea-652    |                     |           6 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | Submitted Login | admin               |        9999 | NULL |
| 1360361333.8800 | RSVP 2    | Submitted From  | ::1                 |       10000 | NULL |
+-----------------+-----------+-----------------+---------------------+-------------+------+
```

My PHP is a little rusty so I'm wondering what's the most efficient way to iterate through the only unique field ('submit_time') to isolate the entries?

Comment: Do you have the `submit_time` and want to get all rows that have the same? If so, `SELECT field_name, field_value FROM mytable WHERE submit_time = ? ORDER BY field_order`.

Comment: I want to show all the entries on the same page, just grouped by `submit_time`.  The list of `submit_time`s therefore needs to be generated automatically.

Comment: Ah right. OK, use this query first: `SELECT submit_time FROM mytable GROUP BY submit_time ORDER BY submit_time DESC` as your outer loop, then the one above as your inner loop. This one will list your `submit_times` uniquely, and you can then use that to get your key/value pairs. I've used `DESC` to get them in reverse chronological order, drop this if you want them oldest-first.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I didn't think of handling it via MySQL, let me give that a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by creating an array with the unique `submit_time` fields and then looping through each of those with that as a variable in the query.  For those of you interested here is the result.

```
$group = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits GROUP BY submit_time');

while ($st = mysql_fetch_row($group)) {
    $myarray[] = $st[0];
}

foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    $query = "SELECT field_value FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE submit_time = ".$value;
    $entry = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($entry)) {
        if (!empty($row[0])) {
            echo $row[0];
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }

    echo '<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Great stuff, always good to add your own answer: +1. Bear in mind that without an `ORDER` clause, you will get your submit_time values in an undefined order, so it would be wise to add one. Also, you can't `SELECT *` in the first query, since you have a `GROUP BY` that would not permit it - think you meant `SELECT submit_time`.

Comment: You read my mind, thats the problem I'm working on now.  I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using `$result = mysql_query();` or something like that to get these values.
Then you do the following:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result /*or your result varname*/ )) {
    //do the things you want to do
}
```

$row now is an associative array with the fields the mySql table contains. In your case you could use this for printing the `field_name`-column (just an example):

```
//inside the while-loop:
echo $row["field_name"]."<br/>";
```

This is how you can read every entry of the table. each repeating of the loop increments the row number you're reading out. If you're at the end or there is an error, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns `false` and the loop is quit.

Comment: I think this would work fine if it was organized like a typical DB table (i.e. with a proper index) but I need something else here.

Comment: If you're using `mysql_query();`, this will work, if there's a index or not. The `$result` var contains all found rows. Just give it a try